# vue.config.js to access specific location

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I am running a VueJS SPA app on top of a Flask webserver.

I am using Vue CLI 3 with a vue.config.js file with default values.

The resulting application is structured like this:

```
static/
    dist/
        index.html
        css/
        js/
            app.js
            file1.js
            file2.js
```

I am using the app as a frontend for Flask and Flask is serving the static files from the static folder as per above. As such when the app.js file reference file1.js it needs to reference it as static/dist/js/file1.js. Currently it appears to be referencing it as js/file1.js.

How can I give a path prefix to Vue CLI not to put files in a specific path, but to reference files from a specific parent path no matter where they are?

Comment: https://cli.vuejs.org/config/

Comment: I suspect configureWebpack option is what I need to use